# Dynamic Checkboxes that Refer to Filtered Content from Another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My problem is that I need to create a sheet that refers to a filter, but has its own connected check box. By which I mean the following:

I have a Master Sheet with all the data sorted by date. It looks like

```
Name, Date, Genre

The Great Gatsby, 1925-04-10, Drama
...
The Metamorphosis, 1915-12-31, Absurdism
...
Don Quixote, 1605-1231, Satire
...
```

Then I have several user sheets. These display only certain genres they are interested in. This is done via the following (for one user example):

```
Read, Name, Date, Genre

TRUE/FALSE Checkbox, =FILTER('Master Sheet'!A:C, ('Master Sheet'!C:C="Drama")+('Master Sheet'!C:C="Satire"))
```

In this, I am currently putting the TRUE/FALSE Checkbox in manually and then populating the remaining columns from the Master Sheet via a FILTER.

What I would like to do is have a checkbox in the users' individual spreadsheets so that they can mark off books as they read them. The problem is that, as books are being added to the Master Sheet all the time, the list grows and change. As it is, if a user has clicked a checkbox in the Read column, when the Master Sheet gets updated, said checkbox will become out of sync because of the dynamic Date sorting in the Master Sheet. There is no 'link' between the content, essentially.

Obviously I could add a checkbox column for every user in the Master Sheet and pull from that in the filter - but then the users can't click said checkbox (they would need to go to the Master Sheet to do so) and it would get unwieldy having so many extra columns for each individual user in the master data sheet.

Is there some way to dynamically populate checkboxes that are specific to each row populated by the FILTER - and then keep them consistent across Master Sheet changes?

Comment: You have added tags for Excel as well as Google Sheets. Please choose just one spreadsheet format.

Comment: At the moment you have a "Master" list of books, but you also need a master list of "read books". If you have a small number of users, then you could probably add this to the existing "Master" book list. But if your number of users will grow, then the "proper" way is to have a second sheet containing records of the users and the books that they have read.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without awful copy/pasted data redundancy any time there's an update? Could UUIDs somehow help?

Comment: `awful copy/pasted data redundancy any time there's an update`. I suppose whether this is "awful" or not is a matter of opinion. A UUID is just another way of doing the same thing. With respect, the goal is to establish that a given user has (or not) read a given book title. No amount of filtering/querying/whatever will be of any benefit unless there is a record of books read.

Comment: Another workaround would be to remove the filter in the "Master" book list, that way the data will remain in the same order.